# 12.04 Ubuntu Software Center won't download when I click install

Tags: 12.04, installation, software-center

Tried all the fixes here to no avail. Ubuntu Software Center opens fine, but when I attempt to click the `Install` button for any of the programs, no authentication pops up (as it does on my other 12.04 install) and nothing downloads. It flashes installing and then stops.

Under the `Edit` menu I cannot alter the checkmarks on tabs such as `Ubuntu Software` and `Downloadable from the Internet`. It lets me click the check mark and turns it right back off again.

`apt-get` from Terminal works fine for the same programs.

It seems like my permissions were locked somehow, but I don't know what directory it wants to download into and don't know how to fix it. Do I need to run Software Center as a super user?

This was an upgrade from 11.10 if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove Software Center, and re-installing it.  to do that just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get purge software-center
```

and when that's done, do

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Then do

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Purge and reinstall does not work. Running program from a terminal works; non-root cannot run either Update Manager or Software Center by default. Icons are there but everything appears broken when you try to run it without any request for authentication. Instead, run apps from terminal with 'gksudo' in front. 

So now every time I want to run these programs I use the terminal and everything is great. 

gksudo nautilus (run file manager as root)
gksudo software-center (install software, when you click install it actually works)
gksudo update-manager  (run updates that actually install)

Comment: I wouldn't remove the `software-center` until I'd tried everything else. That would include `sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center`.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is very simple, just select the software you want to install, obviously the "install" button will not work, so instead click on File on the top menu, and click "Install", and see it will work.